# empty space in url makes no pages in php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem working with `.htacess` file and url aliasing and `GET` method to retrieve values

### .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable Rewriting 
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^search-location/(\w+)/?$ findjob4.php?loc=$1
</IfModule>
```

### findjob.php file

```
if (isset($_GET['loc']) or !empty($_GET['loc'])) {
    $d_location = $_GET['loc'];
    echo "Location : " . $d_location;
}
```

below are the operations what i did,

```
URL 1   :   www.example.com/search-location/london
ouput   :   Location : london
status  :   Good


URL 2   :   www.example.com/search-location/north-london
output  :   Error 404 , Object not found!
Status  :   The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.


URL 3   :   www.example.com/search-location/north%20london
output  :   Error 404 , Object not found!
Status  :   The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

But i could not get the values of those `GET` method `loc` variables, if i give a `. .`  (space) or `-` (hypen) between  url values.
how do i get the values from the url..

thanks

Comment: `isset($_GET['loc']) or !empty($_GET['loc'])` makes no sense. Remove one of them (i'd get rid of `isset` as `!empty` includes that check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `(\w+)` with `(.*)` which matches anything instead of just a word. Or if you want just characters and a dash (-) you can use this: `([A-Za-z-]+)`
Also there's this [tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) that helps debugging .htaccess stuff.